# Combinations in the right order

Tags: r

I am dealing with combinations of variables. In my model the combination (A,B) would be similar to (B,A). I would like to reshape my data in order to get similar combinations in the same order.

I try to used the `duplicated` function and to work with the `paste` function but I do not sort out the issue.

This is my first table :

```
df <- data.frame(V1=c("A","A","A","B","B","B"),
                 V2=c("B","C","D","A","D","A"))
```

This what I would like to obtain :

```
df2 <- data.frame(V1=c("A","A","A","B","B","B"),
                  V2=c("B","C","D","A","D","A"),
                  Test=c("OK","OK","OK","FALSE","OK","FALSE"),
                  V1b=c("A","A","A","A","B","A"),
                  V2b=c("B","C","D","B","D","B"))
```

Comment: Are you saying that it somehow should detect that (B,A) is not the right order, declare it false and then say it should be (A,B)? Then how do you determine the right order?

Comment: Yes - the right order is not really important for me. Indeed I just would like that all (A,B) and (B,A) to become either (A,B) ; (A,B) or (B,A) ; (B;A)

Comment: I think that the algorithm could be iterative => I have the combination (B,A). If (A,B) exist in the upper part of the table, then put (A,B) instead of (B,A) but I do not know how to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the "right order" is the alphabetical order, you can use

```
alphabetical <- function(x,y){x < y}
```

which return true when x,y is sorted alphabetically and false otherwise.

EDIT : here is a working solution :

```
df_sorted <- df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(Test = alphabetical(as.character(V1),as.character(V2))) %>% 
                 mutate(V1b = if (Test) {
                  as.character(V1)
                } else {
                  as.character(V2)
                }) %>% 
                mutate(V2b = if (Test) {
                  as.character(V2)
                } else {
                  as.character(V1)
                })
```

Answer (score 1):

With `dplyr`, you can do:

```
df %>%
 mutate(V1b = pmin(V1, V2), 
        V2b = pmax(V1, V2),
        Test = paste0(V1, V2) != paste0(V1b, V2b))

  V1 V2 V1b V2b  Test
1  A  B   A   B FALSE
2  A  C   A   C FALSE
3  A  D   A   D FALSE
4  B  A   A   B  TRUE
5  B  D   B   D FALSE
6  B  A   A   B  TRUE
```